# Wrong Employment Information in Job application form but correct information in Background verification form

Tags: resume, job-offer, human-resources, background-check

I am working for 2 years in my present company and in my last and second last company I had worked for 5 months and 6 months respectively. I have always stated this information correctly in all my previous resumes, except few days back I made a blunder where I removed the second last company and merged its 6 months with the last company making the work experience 11 months v/s 5 months, as I was feeling that those two small work tenure won't look good.

Though I didn't intended to use this resume, I mistakenly send this version of resume while applying for a new Job, got interview call, cleared all rounds and got offer letter. After that they mailed me a Job application form which I had filled, scanned and mailed back. In this Job application form again to match up with my resume I filled in the same wrong information of adding 6 months experience in second last company into the last company making the last company experience to 11 months, while removing the second last company completely (another reason as the hiring team was happy with everything except my short stay duration of 11 month in the last job).

Later they send me link to their background verification agency website. In their website THOUGH, I filled in the CORRECT information about the last (5 months) and second last company (6 months) supported by the relieving certificates.

Now I am worrying :(, as both my resume and the Job application have wrong information, but the form which I filled and submitted on the background checking agency website has correct information. When either the new company or the background check agency cross verify with my Job application they will find the mismatch.

I wanted some advice about what steps I can take now to prevent the offer getting cancelled or is it not that severe and they might ignore or give a chance for me to explain.

Any advice is highly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: VTC as looking for an advice: "_I mistakenly send this version of resume_" ... "_again to match up with my resume, I filled in the same wrong information_" so you filled a bad resume and sent it, and you knew that you sent a purposely-filled wrong resume, but you still filled wrong info again. You are a little late to take "_steps to prevent the offer getting cancelled_"

Comment: I have edited the line ... hope it make some sense to you about my stand. BTW: what is full form of VTC

Comment: @TulluArya "VTC" stands for "Vote to Close". There is currently one vote to close on the basis of the question being off-topic.

Comment: @TulluArya, This wasn't an innocent mistake. You purposefully intended to lie, whether it was to them or at a later date to some other employer. My advice. Keep quiet. Keep on looking for other jobs as your backups (as if you had not received an offer already). Hope that they do not notice, or that if someone notices that they do not flag it. Coming clean now wouldn't do any good. It would only bring unnecessary attention to it. And if rejected, you can try explaining it yourself, but don't count on that explanation working at all (unless it's for a minimum wage job or for a car salesman job).

Comment: Could you please specify the country, that would be helpful to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

The claim to have "mistakenly" sent the wrong resume is not a good idea at all, even if true. It suffers from serious problems:

- Creating the false resume without intending to use it seems pointless.
- You clearly knew you had sent the false resume when you filled out the application form. If sending it were a genuine mistake you would have immediately apologized, sent a corrected resume, and filled out the application form correctly.
- It seems the "11 month" stay in the last job was discussed - another missed opportunity to apologize and correct the application.

It all looks as though you not only lied to them in the past, but are still lying to try to whitewash previous lies.

I think you have two options now. One is to say nothing and hope the discrepancy does not get noticed. If it does, you will certainly lose the offer. The other option is to abandon lying as a strategy. Take responsibility for the false resume and application, but claim to have learned your lesson and never repeat such dishonesty.

Comment: Pretty much this, the good news, is a 5 month difference at a company is the deciding factor your likely better off.  Hopefully, you learned your lesson, that lying on your resume isn’t worth it.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, you lied on your resume and application and it will most likely come out in the progress of the background check. It may help your case to come clean to the new employer before the background check completes but it's going to be hard to paint this in a good light I'm afraid.

I think you need to prepare yourself to lose this offer.